# How to implement own format to replace UnityFS .bundle?

Tags: unity-game-engine, addressables

I'm using Addressables to build assets. This process creates bunch of .bundle files (in UnityFS format).

I would like to create my own asset bundle format (e.g. [IPFS's .car](https://car.ipfs.io/)).

Is there any class that I can implement to override the default Unity's archive format which can be used for specific Addressables Group?

Answer (score 0):

Addressables' scripts responsible for build process can be found in *Packages/Addressables/Editor/Build/DataBuilders*. Their references can be found in assets files at *Assets/AddressableAssetsData/DataBuilders* (settings created when setting up *Addressables* package for the first time).

A new asset can be created in DataBuilders/ via contextual menu: *Create->Addressables->Content Builders->Default Build Script*. This new asset has reference to build script (reference can be changed in *Debug* view in *Inspector*).

Overridden script (can be placed anywhere in *Assets/*) can look like:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Build.BuildPipelineTasks;
using UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Settings;
using UnityEngine.Build.Pipeline; // For: BundleDetails.
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.Build.DataBuilders
{
  using Debug = UnityEngine.Debug;
  public class BuildScriptCustomMode : BuildScriptPackedMode
  {

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override string Name
    {
      get { return "Custom Build Script"; }
    }

    /// Creates a name for an asset bundle using the provided information.
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override string ConstructAssetBundleName(AddressableAssetGroup assetGroup, BundledAssetGroupSchema schema, BundleDetails info, string assetBundleName)
    {
      string bundleNameWithHashing = base.ConstructAssetBundleName(assetGroup, schema, info, assetBundleName);
      bundleNameWithHashing = bundleNameWithHashing.Replace(".bundle", ".custom.bundle");
      Debug.Log("bundleNameWithHashing: " + bundleNameWithHashing);
      return bundleNameWithHashing;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override TResult DoBuild<TResult>(AddressablesDataBuilderInput builderInput, AddressableAssetsBuildContext aaContext)
    {
      var genericResult = AddressableAssetBuildResult.CreateResult<TResult>();
      // genericResult = base.DoBuild<TResult>(builderInput, aaContext); // Original build script.
      // Override custom build here...
      // Location of current built files: aaContext.locations.
      return genericResult;
    }
  }
}
```

Other methods can be overridden as well when needed. Haven't tested the whole process yet, but that's the good start. The best is to look how `BuildScriptPackedMode` class script does that.

Read more: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.21/manual/editor/building-content/BuildingContent.html.